# Is there a more concise way to check for existence of an object before iterating over it?

Tags: coffeescript

Let's say I have two objects:

```
coffee> objA = {a: 4, b: [1,2,3,4], c: [5,6,7]}
{ a: 4, b: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], c: [ 5, 6, 7 ] }
coffee> objB = { a: 4, b: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
{ a: 4, b: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
```

I want to run them through the same loop:

```
do (obj) -> 
  for n in obj.b
    do (b) -> 
      ... stuff here 
  for n in obj.c
    do (c) -> 
      ... stuff here
```

But `c` may not exist, so I put an `if` in front:

```
do (obj) -> 
  for n in obj.b
    do (b) -> 
      ... stuff here 
  if obj.c?   
    for n in obj.c
      do (c) -> 
        ... stuff here
```

Which leads me to wonder if there's a better way to handle that `if obj.c?`. I thought a `when` would handle it but the when gets evaluated after the loop object is assigned, leading to `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the null-alternative form of the question mark:

```
objB = { a: 4, b: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
for n in objB.c ? []
    console.debug("Hi there #{n}")
```